# Type-casting pointer to array member in C++ and operator precedence

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, casting, type-conversion

I have to type-cast a member of a const array. But, the way the ***precedence*** works here has got me confusing. Does the below 2 options result in the same pointer?

```
const char *pPacket;
char * destination_pointer;
```

Option 1:

```
destination_pointer = &pPacket[index];
```

Option 2:

```
destination_pointer = (char *)&pPacket[index];
```

Comment: Same, cast is unnecessary. memcpy copies memory block from one place to another place, it doesn't care underlying type of source or destination.

Comment: This was to be solely done to remove LINT(static code analysis tool) warning!

Comment: why don't fix signature instead (`myClass::GetPacket(char *pPacket)`) ?

Comment: @Aad: The warning was there for a good reason. As (presumably) was the compiler error. Why does the function take a `const` pointer if it's not going to treat it as `const`?

Comment: Dear all, edited the question to avoid attention to other points...

Comment: You should use `const_cast` instead of C-cast anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep should be the same.

Option two is just explicitly casting the element of the array to `char *`.

`const char *pPacket;` creates a pointer to constant data which cannot be modified through the pointer. So as long as you don't change what's in memory, it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Adding/removing `const`/`volatile` doesn't change the value of the pointer/reference.